# Creating a ruby optimized version while dumping in snakeyaml

Tags: java, serialization, yaml, snakeyaml

I recently tried to dump an object to an `.yaml` file and everything works fine. But, the problem is I want an ruby optimized version since the output file is used by ruby. Currently, the dumped file contains the following:

```
{foo: null, bar: null, foo1: null, bar1: null}
```

But, I need the output as follows:

```
--- 
bar: ~
bar1: ~
foo: ~
foo1: ~
```

So, how can I do that using snakeyaml. I got the utf-8 optimized version of ruby at http://www.yamllint.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question then you might use `yaml.dumpAsMap(map)` instead of `yaml.dump(map)`, and a `TreeMap` and then `String.replace(String, String)` like

```
Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put("foo", null);
map.put("bar", null);
map.put("foo1", null);
map.put("bar1", null);

Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
String output = yaml.dumpAsMap(map); // yaml.dump(map);
System.out.println("---");
System.out.println(output.replace("null", "~"));
```

Output is (as requested)

```
------
bar: ~
bar1: ~
foo: ~
foo1: ~
```

Comment: @Gowtham A Map is not an array. So you'd use `yaml.dump(array)` which would give you an array. What are you asking exactly?

Comment: It works for normal vars, but doesn't work for dumping array of objects. A sample validation: [http://i.stack.imgur.com/9vaM2.png](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9vaM2.png). As you can see `tracks` is the array of objects of class `Track`

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out. Thanks.